# jquery won't select all elements except title inside contenteditable div

Tags: jquery, ajax, contenteditable

I am trying to save content from contenteditable div in data base using jquery ajax.
Problem is in the line `page_body`: `$(".class2").not('h2').html()` selects title and I want to select everything else but the title. The same thing is using `:not` - I end up having two titles and when I use `$(".class2").next()` it saves only 1st paragraph, and `$(".class2").nextAll()` only 2nd paragraph.

My HTML:

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2" contentEditable="true" id="id">
        <h2 id="title">title</h2> 
        <p id="page_body">body</p>
    </div>
    <button class="gen_submit">save</button>
</div>
```

My Jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

     $('.class1').on('keydown', ".class2", function (event) {
         event.stopPropagation();
         var unsaved = $('<div class="unsaved"><p>m1</p></div>');
         $(this).append(unsaved);
     })
         .on('unload', function (event) {
         event.stopPropagation();
         alert("m2");
     })
         .on('click', '.gen_submit', function (event) {
         event.stopPropagation();
         event.preventDefault();
         $('.unsaved').remove();
         $.ajax({
             url: "save.php",
             dataType: "html",
             type: "POST",
             data: {
                 id: $(".class2").prop("id"),
                 title: $("#title").html(),
                 page_body: $(".class2").not('h2').html()
             },

             success: function (data, status) {
                 console.log("Success!!!");
                 console.log(data);
                 console.log(status);
             }
         });
     });
 })
```

Please help! I am so sorry if it's obvious question but I am new to all of this.

Comment: Any reason why you couldn't do `$('.class2 p')` or something similar?

Comment: For some reason it only selected the first paragraph ?

Comment: maybe you should wrap the paragraphs in a div and select that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it isn't the most robust answer, you can grab the index of the h2 closing tag `</h2>` and add the length of the tag (5) to get the rest of the content using `substring()`.

```
var page_body_location = $(".class2").html().indexOf('</h2>')+5
var page_body = $(".class2").html().substring(page_body_location)
```

[jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/rbW3V/)

Comment: Actually, your solution is the best. All others didn't work after a while, for some reason. I expanded it with var page_body_location = $(".class2").html().indexOf('</p>')+4; since additional <p id=page_body></p> tags were generated after every click on button. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$(".class2").not('h2')
```

says select all class2 that are not also h2 but you want the children of the class2"

**USE THIS ONE**:

```
$(".class2").children().not('h2').html()
```

EDIT: this has the same net effect but less efficiency:

```
$(".class2>*").not('h2').html()
```

This says find everything, then find those that are children of class2 within everything, and then find those not h2.  This the right to left selector in jQuery where it gets EVERYTHING first is not the best and the .children() selector would be better.

EDIT: For compact version:

```
$('.class2>*:not("h2")').html()
```

Find everything not h2, then find those that are in everything, then find those that are children of class2 - likely less efficient still than the previous and the `.children()` selector would be more efficient.

Comment: This is a better solution to the problem. Good answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
page_body: $(".class2 > *").not('h2').html();
```

Comment: That would remove the h2 from the page, not sure if that's what is needed

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 'not' on the children(). But then since you don't have a parent node, you have to essentially make a dummy to wrap so you can then output the html(), like this:

```
    page_body: $(".class2").children().not('h2').clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the clone() method if you ever need to manipulate the DOM elements, but don't want to disturb the original ones.

```
// Clone the div with the "class2" class & remove all h2 descendants.
var $clone = $('.class2').clone();
$clone.find('h2').remove();


// In your ajax call
data: {
     id: $('.class2').prop('id'),
     title: $('#title').html(),
     page_body: $clone.html()
 },
```